# BFS Algorithm in Memgraph on the karate club friendship network dataset

Tags: graph-databases, memgraphdb

I want to run the Breadth-First Search (BFS) Algorithm in Python in Memgraph. How can I do that on the karate club friendship network dataset?

Comment: Your question is likely to get closed as it is not very focused, but even a simple Google search seems likely to yield what you are looking for - https://discourse.memgraph.com/t/how-to-run-a-python-bfs-algorithm-on-a-dataset-in-memgraph/282.  Ideally a question should include details of what you have tried already. Please refer to [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found out that first, you need a driver to connect to Memgraph from a Python script. The suggested way is the open-source library [GQLAlchemy](https://memgraph.com/docs/gqlalchemy/) as it contains a lot of useful features for developing graph applications in Python.

Once you connect with GQLAlchemy and load the dataset through Memgraph Lab, you can run the BFS algorithm using the Cypher query language.

For example:

```
results = memgraph.execute_and_fetch
("MATCH path=({id: "0"})-[:FRIENDS_WITH *bfs]-({id: "33"}) 
RETURN path;")
```